# Unable to add image

Tags: support, images

This is my first time posting, so the answer is probably obvious, but I can't find it in the help center...how do I add an image to an answer? When I click the image icon and browse to the image, it seems to upload (I can see it on the Imgur link directly) but it doesn't appear embedded in the [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/145757/162053)...what am I doing wrong? Possibly related: the hyperlinks don't seem to work, either...

Comment: As Glorfindel said, the link you tried to insert included some weird characters (Google does this sometimes to highlight the text you searched on the resulting page). This link broke the parser, and also the link to your image. I've fixed it, and now your image shows up like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that the first link is too complicated for the Markdown parser (which is generating the HTML from your post's 'source code') can't handle some of the special characters in your first link: `https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/selecting-grouping-linking-layers.html#:~:text=When%20selecting%2C%20Ctrl%2Dclick%20(,%2C%20choose%20Select%20%3E%20All%20Layers.`

Try using a link shortener, or remove the part starting with `#`.